# sending a changing variable to a def function by a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, beagleboneblack

I'm working on making an automated greenhouse, by measuring temperature, there are things to be activated like open a window, or control a fan, according to the value changes in temperature, I made this program on python using tkinter so when the conditions else, elif, if are inside a function def they send prints, but when I run my code even with the value temperature changing I send this temperature value to other def function for them to use so they seem to use always the first if and ignore the rest conditions. I tried debugging but as I'm working on Geany in a Beaglebone I can't seem to find the option.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import thread
import Tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC

#PWM.start(channel,duty,freq=1000,polarity=0)
#values for duty are from 0.0 to 100.0 (%)

PWM.start("P8_13",0,50)
GPIO.setup("P8_15",GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("P8_15",GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup("P8_16",GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("P8_16",GPIO.LOW)


PWM.start("P9_14",0,50)



ADC.setup()

def med_temp(close):
        adclose=close
        while adclose < 1:
                        raw=ADC.read('P9_33')*1800
                        t=raw/10
                        temp1=round(t,0)
                        tempvar.set(temp1)
                        sleep(1)

def window_thread(close, value):
        gpioclose1=close
        temp=value

        while gpioclose1<1:
                if temp>=30.0 :
                        #print temp
                        duty=90
                        PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",duty)
                        sleep(.1)
                        windvar.set('OPEN', )
                        label11["fg"]='green'

                else:
                        duty=0
                        PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",duty)
                        sleep(.1)
                        windvar.set('CLOSE')
                        label11["fg"]='red'



def fan1_thread(close,value):
        gpioclose=close
        temp=value
        while gpioclose<1:
                if temp<=23.0:
                        #out
                        GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.LOW)#OUT
                        GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.HIGH)
                        sleep(.1)
                        ventvar.set('OUT ')
                        label6["fg"]='#6c132b'


                elif temp>=40.0:
                #in
                        GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.HIGH)#IN
                        GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.LOW)
                        sleep(.1)
                        ventvar.set('IN ')
                        label6["fg"]='#5cbdea'

                else:
                        #off
                        GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.LOW)#OFF
                        GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.LOW)
                        sleep(.1)
                        ventvar.set('OFF ')
                        label6["fg"]='red'






def fan2_thread(close,value):
                pwmclose=close
                temp=value
                while pwmclose<1:
                        if temp<23.0:
                                duty=100
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",duty)
                                sleep(.1)
                                dutyvar.set(duty)

                        elif temp<25.0 and temp>=23.0:
                                duty=50
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",duty)
                                sleep(.1)
                                dutyvar.set(duty)

                        elif temp>=40.0:
                                duty=100
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",duty)
                                sleep(.1)
                                dutyvar.set(duty)
                        else:
                                duty=0
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",duty)
                                sleep(.1)
                                dutyvar.set(duty)


def salir():
        pwmclose = 1
        adclose =1
        gpioclose =1
        gpioclose1=1
        PWM.stop("P8_13")
        PWM.cleanup()
        GPIO.cleanup()
        exit()




mainw = tk.Tk()
mainw.title("Greenhouse control")

#contenido


tempvar = tk.DoubleVar()
ventvar = tk.StringVar()
dutyvar = tk.DoubleVar()
windvar = tk.StringVar()

label1 = tk.Label(mainw,text='      Temperature: ', width=len('        Temperature: '),bg='red')
label2 = tk.Label(mainw, textvariable=tempvar, bg='white')
label3 = tk.Label(mainw, text='C', width=len('C'), bg='white')
label4 = tk.Label(mainw, text='       FAN   ', width=len('                  FAN   '),bg='purple')
label5 = tk.Label(mainw, text='Estado: ',width=len('Estate: '))
label6 = tk.Label(mainw, textvariable=ventvar,bg='white')
slider = tk.Scale(mainw, variable = dutyvar,from_=100, to=0)#
label9 = tk.Label(mainw, text='    WINDOW      ', width=len('                   WINDOW     '), bg='purple')
label10 = tk.Label(mainw, text='Estate: ',width=len('State: '))
label11 = tk.Label(mainw, textvariable=windvar, bg='white')

thread.start_new_thread(window_thread,(0,tempvar,))
thread.start_new_thread(med_temp, (0,))
thread.start_new_thread(fan1_thread, (0,tempvar,))
thread.start_new_thread(fan2_thread, (0,tempvar,))

salirButton = tk.Button(mainw, text='EXIT', command=salir,activeforeground='red')

#set layout
label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label3.grid(row=0, column=2)
label4.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=4)
label5.grid(row=2, column=0)
label6.grid(row=2, column=1)
slider.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2)
label9.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4)
label10.grid(row=4, column=0)
label11.grid(row=4, column=1)
salirButton.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4)
mainw.mainloop()
```

So I went and send print the temperature inside the if and I get PY_VARO. In this line
    thread.start_new_thread(window_thread,(0,tempvar,))
I'm sending to the def function the 0 to close the function and I'm sending tempvar that is a double. And if I write
    thread.start_new_thread(window_thread,(0,tempvar.get,))
I get in the print temp inside the if:
    bound method DoubleVar.get of Tkinter.DoubleVar

SO I guess if conditions are not being ignored but I'm sending the wrong value to the def when I start the thread? What the correct format to send it to a function?

Comment: I think you have typos temp=valor (value).  Also, the functions never exit, i.e. only execute on the initial start up, because the while variable does not change, i.e. "while adclose < 1", addclose never changes so the while() loop never exits.  Time to simplify the program and test each function individually without threads while testing.

Comment: I get PY_VARO -- Tkinter's StringVar() et all use get and set methods to access the values.  Effbot's page illustrates the set() method http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Comment: Tkinter and threads do not mix and should be avoided. Instead look at using the `after` method: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Comment: Curly Joe The while close until I push the EXIT button. Thanks ebarr I'm gonna put all inside one thread, I shouldnt be using that many threads I guess I had a bad concept of thread, I upload if I solved it later.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I was doing it wrong by creating many threads. I finally got my greenhouse to do what I wanted. Here's my final code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import thread
import Tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC

#PWM.start(channel,duty,freq=1000,polarity=0)
#values for duty are from 0.0 to 100.0 (%)

#VENTILADOR
PWM.start("P8_13",0,4000)
GPIO.setup("P8_15",GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("P8_15",GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup("P8_16",GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("P8_16",GPIO.LOW)

#VENTANA
PWM.start("P9_14",1,50)#start closed servo


#temperatura
ADC.setup()

def med_temp(close):
        adclose=close
        while adclose < 1:
                        raw=ADC.read('P9_33')*1800
                        t=raw/10
                        temp=round(t,0)
                        tempvar.set(temp)
                        if temp <23:
                                GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.LOW)#OUT
                                GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.HIGH)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",100)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",1)#closed
                                sleep(.1)
                                windvar.set('CLOSE')
                                label11["fg"]='red'
                                ventvar.set('OUT ')
                                label6["fg"]='#6c132b'

                                dutyvar.set(100)

                        elif temp >= 23 and temp < 25:
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",50)
                                GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.LOW)#OUT
                                GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.HIGH)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",1)#closed
                                sleep(.1)

                                windvar.set('CLOSE')
                                label11["fg"]='red'

                                ventvar.set('OUT ')
                                label6["fg"]='#6c132b'

                                dutyvar.set(50)

                        elif temp>=25 and temp<30:
                                GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.LOW)#OFF
                                GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.LOW)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",0)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",1)#closed
                                sleep(.1)

                                windvar.set("CLOSE")
                                label11["fg"]='red'

                                ventvar.set('OFF ')
                                label6["fg"]='red'

                                dutyvar.set(0)
                                #print temp
                                #print'OFF 0% CLOSE'

                        elif temp>=30 and temp < 35:
                                GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.LOW)#OFF
                                GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.LOW)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",0)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",5)#opened
                                sleep(.1)

                                windvar.set('OPEN')
                                label11["fg"]='green'

                                ventvar.set('OFF ')
                                label6["fg"]='red'

                                dutyvar.set(0)
                                print temp
                                #print'OFF 0% OPEN'

                        elif temp>=35 and temp < 40:
                                GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.HIGH)#IN
                                GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.LOW)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",50)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",5)#opened
                                sleep(.1)

                                windvar.set('OPEN')
                                label11["fg"]='green'

                                ventvar.set('IN ')
                                label6["fg"]='#5cbdea'

                                dutyvar.set(50)
                                print temp
                                #print'IN 50% OPEN'
                        else:
                                GPIO.output("P8_15", GPIO.HIGH)#IN
                                GPIO.output("P8_16", GPIO.LOW)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P8_13",100)
                                PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14",5)#opened
                                sleep(.1)

                                windvar.set('OPEN')
                                label11["fg"]='green'

                                ventvar.set('IN ')
                                label6["fg"]='#5cbdea'

                                dutyvar.set(100)
                                print temp
                                #print'IN 100% OPEN'
                        sleep(1)


def salir():
        adclose =1
        #gpioclose =1
        #gpioclose1=1
        PWM.stop("P8_13")
        PWM.stop("P9_14")
        PWM.cleanup()
        GPIO.cleanup()
        exit()




mainw = tk.Tk()
mainw.title("Control de Invernadero")

#contenido


tempvar = tk.DoubleVar()
ventvar = tk.StringVar()
dutyvar = tk.DoubleVar()
windvar = tk.StringVar()

label1 = tk.Label(mainw,text='      Temperatura: ', width=len('        Temperatura: '),bg='red')
label2 = tk.Label(mainw, textvariable=tempvar, bg='white')
label3 = tk.Label(mainw, text='C', width=len('C'), bg='white')
label4 = tk.Label(mainw, text='       VENTILADOR   ', width=len('                  VENTILADOR   '),bg='purple')
label5 = tk.Label(mainw, text='Estado: ',width=len('Estado: '))
label6 = tk.Label(mainw, textvariable=ventvar,bg='white')
slider = tk.Scale(mainw, variable = dutyvar,from_=0, to=100, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)#
label9 = tk.Label(mainw, text='    VENTANA       ', width=len('                   VENTANA     '), bg='purple')
label10 = tk.Label(mainw, text='Estado: ',width=len('Estado: '))
label11 = tk.Label(mainw, textvariable=windvar, bg='white')

thread.start_new_thread(med_temp, (0,))


salirButton = tk.Button(mainw, text='SALIR', command=salir,activeforeground='red')

#set layout
label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label3.grid(row=0, column=2)
label4.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=4)
label5.grid(row=2, column=0)
label6.grid(row=2, column=1)
slider.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2)
label9.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4)
label10.grid(row=4, column=0)
label11.grid(row=4, column=1)
salirButton.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4)
mainw.mainloop()
```